# Deduct the area of an ellipsoid whose equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, elliptic-equations

Deduct the area of an ellipsoid whose equation is given by $ \frac {x ^ 2} {a ^ 2} + \frac {y ^ 2} {b ^ 2} + \frac {z ^ 2} {c ^ 2} = $ 1

How to calculate this area using volume difference? Do the volume of this ellipsoid minus the ellipsoid volume of dimensions $' a = a-h, b '= b-h, c' = c-h$, with $h \implies 0$

And if not, how can I solve it? I thought about parameterizing and using Jacobin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult problem (harder than the length of an ellipse), there is no closed-form expression in the general case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Surface_area.

The difference of volumes doesn't work because the thickness is not uniform.

Comment: Parameterize this so that it becomes the expression of a sphere of radius 1. After applying Jacobino, throwing the integral of the spherical surface area, would de-parameterizing help solve?

Comment: @Tortugut: no, there is no closed-form expression in the general case. If you are not familiar with elliptic integrals, drop it.

Comment: Actually closed, but for area could not

Comment: @Tortugut: what ???